# Why background color is orange in Xcode but white in Simulator

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ios7

I have create a page based application using the template.

The color of my DataViewController is orange in Xcode (I have a label, an image and a textview)

[image]

but in simulator the bottom is white instead of orange, why ? How can I change

UPDATE : Storyboard properties

[image]

Comment: Do you mean in Xcode as in Storyboard? check the viewController's code, you probably set the background color back to white, if not then simply set it to orange or whatever in viewDidLoad..

Comment: @ed-less yes in StoryBoard

Answer (score 1):

Based on the limited information you provide, it is possible that another view is covering your background. Set a breakpoint in the view controller and tell the debugger

```
po [self.view recursiveDescription]
```

and examine the frames of all the subviews. A label, for example is white by default, so if the label expands (due to the constraints defined in storyboard), it could cover your background.

Comment: I have updated my post with screenshot of StoryBoard properties. I'm not used to debugger will try.